# Django, Nginx, uwsgi, Kubernetes: unable to connect nginx to uwsgi stream

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, uwsgi

I have a django container and an Ngix container. they work fine with docker-compose, and now im trying to use the images with kubernetes. Everything works fine, except the fact that the nginx container cannot connect to the uwsgi upstream. No response is being returned.

Here are my configuration:

```
# Nginx congifuration
upstream django {
    server admin-api-app:8001 max_fails=20 fail_timeout=10s;  # for a web port socket (we'll use this first),
}

server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  80;
    server_name server localhost my-website-domain.de;
    charset     utf-8;


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

---

```
# Uwsgi file
module          = site_module.wsgi

master          = true
processes       = 5
socket          = :8001
enable-threads  = true
vacuum=True
```

---

```
# Kubernetes

# Backend Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: container-backend
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container-backend
        image: my-djangoimage:latest
        command: ["./docker/entrypoint.sh"]
        ports:        
        - containerPort: 8001        
          name: uwsgi        

      - name: nginx
        image: my-nginx-image:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http        

---

# Backend Service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: admin-api-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Have you tried logging to those containers and checking if they are able to connect to each other?

Comment: Few suggestions:

- Use `server_name $host` instead of `server_name server localhost my-website-domain.de`
- Replace `admin-api-app` by `localhost` (Your containers are seen from localhost within the Pod)
- Force your socket on `0.0.0.0:8001` instead of `:8001`
- Remove the `ports` part in your uwsgi container definition

Comment: thnks. I will try that. I have ended up putting nginx and the application in the same container. and that was working fine

Comment: That's bad practices, but I guess you already know that ;)

Comment: I have always thought so, but after googling, it did not seems to a bad practice from certain source I have read. i was in between and realised that's really bad at the end. my container would have, app + nginx at the end. that does not sound like an anti pattern or bad practice. unless you can try to convince me otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change host in your django upstream because, as far as I understand, you want to connect to your django app located in the same pod where is nginx so try to change:

```
server admin-api-app:8001 max_fails=20 fail_timeout=10s;
```

to

```
server localhost:8001 max_fails=20 fail_timeout=10s;
```

Edit:
To make it work you need to change socket to http-socket but it can be painful/pointless as described here: [Should I have separate containers for Flask, uWSGI, and nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532946/should-i-have-separate-containers-for-flask-uwsgi-and-nginx)

Comment: yeah I want to connect to the container, but the app is not exposing any port. its more of a Unix socket, that's how the two containers should be communicating. at least that's what I know about `uwsgi`